# Handle big data in datatables codeigniter with mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, codeigniter

Please help,
I want to show data which the result of computation on codeigniter. I've 7789 data and it's run so long. Can anybody help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [server side datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). That way you wont have to fetch all 7.8k rows at once

Comment: I've try it before. But it's just work to show data. how about the computation?

Comment: Well if you think computation on the backend is the bottleneck then post your backend code